Any Möbius tranformation from the upper-half plane to the unit disk is an isometry.
I'm reading the book: "A primer on mapping class groups" from Benson Farb, Dan Margalit. On page 19 it states that:
Any Möbius transformation from the upper half-plane to the unit disk is an isometry.
I know that the metric on Poincaré's unit disk is constructed so that Cayley's Möbius Transformation $C(z)=\dfrac{z-i}{z+i}$ is an isometry. Also, I know that all Möbius transformations are conformal, so they send geodesics to geodesics on each model. However, I don't see why would every Möbius transformation be an isometry from the upper-half plane model $\mathbb{H}^2$ and $\Delta$.
I would appreciate it if someone could clarify this.
Thanks!

Conformal maps in general do not map geodesics to geodesics. The question itself was asked many times on this site.

Well, yes, every holomorphic map is conformal... so if we take the natural (!?) metric/Riemmanian structure(s), any holomorphic map will preserve it/them. It's nearly definitional, actually.
